# Add Subtotals to show Grand total in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, logic, shopping-cart, addition

HI i am new to angularjs. In my shopping cart app i am having three textfield for quantity choosing.which are loaded from ng-repeat. I can able to show quantity * Price value for individual products. I need to show a grand total by adding the three subtotals. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

HTML:

```
 <li ng-repeat="orders in ordersList">
                                 <a href="#app/dhosa/{{total}}/{{price}}/{{amount}}"><span class="img"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{orders.image}}" alt="">
                                 </span><span class="product noproduct clearfix"><span class="name">{{orders.product_name}} <b class="doller"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>{{orders.price}}</b></span>
                                 <span class="price">Order ID # {{orders.id}} </span>
                                 <span class="price">- {{orders.created_date}}</span> </a>
                                <div id="field1"><b>Qty:</b>                                    
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-up" data-spin="up"><i id="plus" class="ion-plus-circled"  ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0"></i></a>
                                    <input type="text" id="1" value="{{count}}" class="field">{{orders.price * count}}                              
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="spin-down" data-spin="down"><i class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="count = count - 1" ng-init="count=0"></i></a>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                           </ul>    
                        <p class="amt">Total amount <b>Rs.{{}}</b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to calculate the total in your controller and expose that value to the scope.  Then you can use that scope variable in the view shown above.